# Cambiar a horario local en Highcharts

Tags: angularjs-2.0, highcharts

Buenas, estoy utilizando **Highstock**  de **Highcharts** en `angular 2`, y el eje de las **x** es de tipo **datetime**, los datos que cargo son un valor y una hora determinada para cada valor. El horario de mi región no es el `UTC`, y al mostrar la gráfica la escala del eje **X** me la muestra en horario `UTC`. Pero si veo algún punto me muestra el horario en mi horario local. Porque puede estar pasando esto? Gracias.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código de la gráfica es el siguiente:

```
 this.options = {
    title : { text : event },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        animation: {
              duration: 2000,
              easing: 'swing'
        },
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      title: {
        text: "Horario",
      },
      ordinal: false,
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    yAxis: {
      gapGridLineWidth: 0,
      title: {
          text: event
      },
      labels: {
        style: {
             color: '#89A54E'
        }
      }
    },
    scrollbar: {
      barBackgroundColor: '#8eb4ff',
      buttonBackgroundColor: '#8eb4ff',
    },
    series: [{
        data: graphicData,
        name: event,
        color: 'rgb(27, 98, 176)',    
        shadow:true,
        tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 3,
          },
        dataGrouping: {
          enabled:true,
          approximation:"open",
        }  
    }],
    rangeSelector: {
      enabled:false,
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: true
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },

  };
```

Comment: Requieres definir la zona horaria donde te encuentras, aquí la documentación: [timezone](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/global.timezone)

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema , encontró la solución ?